# Cant save Price for Bundle product magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm create new product **" bundle "** and when choose price is fixed click save ,but product cant save price type is **"fixed"**, product just save is **" dynamic "**, im create product in localhost save normal but im create on host server product cant save price type is fixed(just Dynamic).
pls help me.Thanks You

Answer (score -2):

You can write a module rewrite Model_Bundle_Product_Type to fix this. Write a file have name type.php
extends class Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type and write a function beforeSave
in this function you check post data and set price type for product

```
 if($_postData){

        //set price type
        if($_postData['price']){


            $product->setData('price_type',1);


        }else{

            $product->setData('price_type',0);            

        }
 }
```